# Trouble navigating through my loops in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have already asked people around me and tried countlessly to get this fix program. The program should be able to add the users websites and passwords as many times as  they want to, and show the websites and password they selected.

For now when you answer `would you like to add another website?` with **yes** it dosn't re ask for a new website name and password but just repeats the question `would you like to add another website?`, also when you have entered in a website name and password and answer `would you like to add another website?` with **no** then selected option 1 to see existing accounts, it repeats `would you like to add another website?`, when this should even come up at option one

Inputs and how it should output:

1) find your existing passwords
2) save a new password for your apps
3) see a summary of your password locker
4) exit password locker successfully **1**

You have no stored websites and passwords

1) find your existing passwords
2) save a new password for your apps
3) see a summary of your password locker
4) exit password locker successfully **2**

What is the name of the website/app your are adding? **instagram**

What is the password of your {instagram} account? **bob91**

Would you like to add another website? **yes**

What is the name of the website/app your are adding? **facebook**

What is the password of your {facebook} account? **bob92**

Would you like to add another website? **no**

1) Find your existing passwords
2) Save a new password for your apps
3) See a summary of your password locker
4) Exit password locker successfully **1**

enter the app you want to find the password for **instagram**
websitename = instagram
password = bob91

Full code:

```
vault_apps = []
app_name = ""
def locker_menu_func():
    print('''You have opened the locker, 
Please select what you would like to do,''')
    locker_menu_var = input('''Press: \n1) find your existing passwords \n2) save a new password for your apps\n3) see a summary of your password locke \n4) exit password locker successfully\n---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ''')
    print('''----------------------------------------------------------------''')
    while True:
        if locker_menu_var == "1":
            while len(vault_apps) < 1:
                print('''you have nothing stored''')
                if len(vault_apps) > 1:
                    print(vault_apps)

                break
            break
        if locker_menu_var == "2":
            app_name = input('''
What is the name of the website/app your are adding?
''')
            app_password = input('''What is the password of your {} account?
'''.format(app_name))
            vault_apps.append([app_name, app_password])
            while True: 
                ask_again = input('''Would you like to add another app and password? 
            ''')
                if ask_again.lower() == "yes":
                    locker_menu_var = "2"
                elif ask_again.lower() == "no":
                    locker_menu_func()


                else:
                    print("please enter a valid response") #should repeat if user want to add another website
```

Comment: Recommend using a different approach where you separate the problem into different tasks. Write a function to handle asking the user for input and seeing what they gave you. Write other functions one for each tasks (callback functions). Then write another function with the loop which calls your user input function and then the callback function according to what the user's choice was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This logic is flawed. 
Once you enter the infinite while loop, you have no way to exit it, other than to enter "no". When you enter "yes", the value of locker_menu_var changes, but you donot exit the loop, so it keeps repeating the same menu.

```
            while True:     
            ask_again = input('''Would you like to add another app and password? 
        ''')
            if ask_again.lower() == "yes":
                locker_menu_var = "2"
            elif ask_again.lower() == "no":
                locker_menu_func()
```

You are mixing the looping and recursion, which is making things confusing. One simple way to do this is:

```
vault_apps = []

def locker_menu():

    # the entry message
    msg = '''You have opened the locker, Please select what you would like to do,'''
    print(msg, end="\n\n")

    # nume options
    menu = ["1) find your existing passwords", 
    "2) save a new password for your apps", 
    "3) see a summary of your password locker", 
    "4) exit password locker successfully"]
    menu_string = f"Press:\n{menu[0]}\n{menu[1]}\n{menu[2]}\n{menu[3]}\n"

    # now enter the loop
    while True:

        # input variable
        # NOTE: This variable is inside the loop, 
        # so that the user can enter the value everytime
        # the loop repeates.
        locker_menu_var = input(menu_string)

        if locker_menu_var == "1":
            # retrieve password for an existing record.
            # although it's not a good idea to just print
            # all the records, I am not changing your application logic
            # because I don't see any use in it.

            # you missed one case in your logic,
            # which I have fixed here.
            if len(vault_apps) == 0:
                print("you have nothing stored")
            else:
                print(vault_apps)

        elif locker_menu_var == "2":
            # for a new entry
            # enter your logic here
            an = input("app name: ")
            passw = input("password: ")
            vault_apps.append([an, passw])
            done = False # flag for exiting
            while not done:
                inp = input("enter another?")
                if inp == "yes":
                    # enter logic here
                    an = input("app name: ")
                    passw = input("password: ")
                    vault_apps.append([an, passw])
                else:
                    done = True
        elif locker_menu_var == "3":
            # do something
            pass
        elif locker_menu_var == "4":
            return          

if __name__ == "__main__":
    locker_menu()
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not work because you do not `break` from a `while True:`-loop:

> ```
> while True: 
>     ask_again = input('''Would you like to add another app and password?''')
>     if ask_again.lower() == "yes":
>         locker_menu_var = "2"            <--- does not leave while loop
>     elif ask_again.lower() == "no":
>         locker_menu_func()
>     else:
>         # etc.
> ```

---

Keep your methods small and handling one concern to simplify your control flow, example:

```
vault_apps = {}
# ,2,Hallo,Yuhu,y,Hallo2,Yuh,n,3,4
def menu():
    print('\n'+'-'*40)
    print('1) find your existing passwords')
    print('2) save a new password for your apps')
    print('3) see a summary of your password locker')
    print('4) exit password locker successfully')
    print('-'*40)
    k = None
    while k not in {"1","2","3","4"}:
        k = input("Choose: ")

    return int(k) # return the number chosen 

def input_new_app():
    global vault_apps
    app = None
    while not app:
        app = input("What is your apps name? ")
    pw = None
    while not pw:
        pw = input("What is your apps passphrase? ")
    vault_apps[app]=pw

def print_vault():
    print("Vault content:")
    for key,value in vault_apps.items():
        print(f"  {key:<10}\t==>\t{value}")

def find_password():
    if vault_apps:
        pass
    else:
        print("nothing in your password store")

def main():
    k = None    
    print('You have opened the locker,\nPlease select what you would like to do.')
    while True:  
        choice = menu()
        if choice == 1:
            find_password()
        elif choice == 2:
            input_new_app()
            k = input("Would you like to add another app and password?").lower()
            while  k in {"yes","y"}:
                input_new_app()
        elif choice == 3:
            print_vault()
        elif choice == 4:
            print("Good bye")
            break

main()
```

Output:

```
You have opened the locker,
Please select what you would like to do.

----------------------------------------
1) find your existing passwords
2) save a new password for your apps
3) see a summary of your password locker
4) exit password locker successfully
----------------------------------------
Choose: 1
nothing in your password store

----------------------------------------
1) find your existing passwords
2) save a new password for your apps
3) see a summary of your password locker
4) exit password locker successfully
----------------------------------------
Choose: 2
What is your apps name? A
What is your apps passphrase? 66
Would you like to add another app and password? n
----------------------------------------
1) find your existing passwords
2) save a new password for your apps
3) see a summary of your password locker
4) exit password locker successfully
----------------------------------------
Choose: 3 
Vault content:
  A             ==> 66

----------------------------------------
1) find your existing passwords
2) save a new password for your apps
3) see a summary of your password locker
4) exit password locker successfully
----------------------------------------
Choose: 4
Good bye
```